# Accumulation points and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n) n∈N$ and $(b_n) n∈N$ two sequences, so that each $b_m$ is an accumulation point of the sequence $(a_n) n∈N$. Now let b an accumulation point of $(b_n) n∈N$. Prove b is now also an accumulation point of $(a_n) n∈N$.

Proposed solution:

1. $\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=b_m$ for all $m∈N$
2. $\lim_{n\to \infty}{b_n}=b$

From 1. $a_n$ is a subsequence of $b_n$ and so has the same limit and so at one point $a_n$ will approach b.

I know what I mean in my head....

Comment: I don't believe your first assertion is correct. If $b_m$ is an accumulation point, then that doesn't mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = b_m$. It means that there is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ which converges to $b_m$.

Comment: $a_n$ doesn't necessarily have a limit, so 1. cannot hold.

Comment: Ok so there are subsequences of $a_n$ which have accumulation points $b_m$ and therefore there will be an subsequence of $a_n$ which has b as an accumulation point.

Comment: @babylon That's it more or less. Try setting some $b_m$ arbitrarily close to $b$. Then there are an infinite number of $a_n$ arbitrarily close to $b_m$, and thus also arbitrarily close to $b$. You can formalize this with $\epsilon$ definitions.

Comment: OP: Trevor's approach is the straightforward one.  The one that keeps popping into my head, though, is the following: Let $\{b_i\}$ be a subsequence leading to $b$, and let $\{a_i, j\}$ for each $i$ be a subsequence leading to $b_i$.  Then consider the subsequence $\{a_{1, 1}, a_{2, 2}, \ldots\}$  (I know it's sort of weird, but the diagonalization is the picture in my head.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $b$ is an accumulation point of $(b_n)$, there exists $b_{n_k}\to b$ as $k\to \infty$.

Since for each $k$, $b_{n_k}$ is accumulation point of $(a_n)$ hence $\exists$ subsequence  $a_{n_j}\to b_{n_k}$, as $j\to \infty$.

Hence for each $k$, we can pick $|a_{m_k}- b_{n_k}|\le \frac{1}{k}$ and $m_k<m_{k+1}$. Note $(a_{m_k})$ is subsequence of $(a_n)$

Then by squeeze theorem, $|a_{m_k}- b_{n_k}|\to 0$, hence $a_{m_k}\to b$ as $k\to \infty$.